# Why can't superconducting inductors be used in LC filter design？

Tags: filter, inductance, passive-filter, superconductors

If I replace the copper wire of the coil with superconducting material, what will be the effect on the design of the passive LC filter?why superconducting cant design?

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478223/inductance-in-superconducting-wires-and-the-math

Comment: Do you know that superconductors cannot be used for the coil of an inductor? They are certainly used for the coils of electromagnets.

Comment: I would assume because superconductors are extremely expensive to use, considering the need for cryogenic cooling. If you can make it work with a copper coil, you would use a copper coil.

Answer (score 1):

An inductor can be made from a superconductor.
[Example](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4342326)

Transformers have been made from superconducting wires.
See [Here](https://transformers-magazine.com/magazine/2982-superconducting-transformers-part-i-power/#:%7E:text=Abstract,efficient%20than%20conventional%20power%20transformers.&text=Power%20density%20%E2%80%93%20more%20MVA%20in,decisive%20advantage%20in%20mobile%20applications.)

Comment: Actually My Prof let me do a survey  in  a LC filter by using superconducting inductors.But I havent found any papers about this filed,So I want to know the difficulties in this aspect?thanks for your help very much!!!

Comment: What is the difficulty? The resistance of the inductor is 0, which is the resistance of an "ideal" inductor. The impedance of the inductor would be unaffected by the lack of resistance. (There is however, a maximum field strength that a superconductor can have beyond which it it has non-zero resistance. But we are used to worrying about core saturation in regular non-superconducting circuits, so a maximum field strength is nothing new.)

Comment: so the contradiction have appeared.Now that the Resistance in superconducting coil is equals to coil in  copper coil,it must be made in principal.And the superconducting coil can be used in filter designing.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make LC filters out of superconductors, and filters are one of the larger commercial markets for high temperature superconductors.

This dissertation provides a good overview of the topic

https://researchonline.jcu.edu.au/2025/2/02whole.pdf